# How can I create a USB pass-through switch in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb

I've never done much with the Linux USB stack, it's always just worked. But I'm reading about [USB Dynamic device mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_device_mapping) and wondering if this is possible.

Can I, for example, plug a mouse into one USB port on a Linux machine and issue a command to make it dynamically map the device to another USB port on Linux? And if so what command or toolset should I be looking into?

---

**For the purposes of this question assume I have a USB port that can be in host mode, and another in device mode. I want to know how I would do this, if I had the appropriate hardware.**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143092/discussion-on-question-by-evan-carroll-how-can-i-create-a-usb-pass-through-switc); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I have done something like this in the past:

- Use [USB configfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/gadget_configfs.html) to create wanted USB gadget configuration including e.g. HID devices
  (A gadget can have several device "functions")
- Use `uinput` and `intercept` from [Interception tools framework](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools) to shovel HID events from real device to virtual device on demand

Similar "pass-through" in user-space can be done for devices resembling Audio & video streams, mass storage devices, and devices, that "behave" similar to serial ports.

For Audio&Video, you could use e.g. `ffmpeg` to relay streams between the real  and the emulated (alsa/v4l2) device. E.g. `socat` works for relaying data from serialport-ish devices.

Note, that this is not really "passing through the usb device" using USB-controller hardware, or kernel drivers, but "just" forwarding/bridging the "payload data" from the USB devices, using user-space tools, and some orchestration using scripts, udev and/or systemd.

Other Resources you might find interesting:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget-testing.txt
- https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2019/02/18/modern-usb-gadget-on-linux-and-how-to-integrate-it-with-systemd-part-1/
- https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_the_UVC_gadget_driver_in_Linux
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/functionfs.html

I don't have much time today to elaborate further, but drop me a comment, if something is unclear after googling around using the above info as a starter seed.

Comment: This is a great starting point, thanks a ton! You'll have to give me some time to read this stuff but I'm sure I'll have better questions I can ask after I read up.